# Why Crossref can not detect the DOI of the online published paper? How to fix this issue?

Tags: publications, online-publication

My article has been published online in a JCR journal and it has a DOI which works (yet the issue is not identified). The problem is that this DOI can not be detected by Crossref. When submitting articles with their DOI to our university system, articles are identified if the CrossRef recognizes them. My first question is why Crossref can not identify this DOI? and the second question is can I do something in order that Crossref recognizes this and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably because the publisher has not registered the DOI with Crossref.

See https://www.crossref.org/services/content-registration/.

You can contact the publisher and request them to do this